# Matching items in two arrays iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, string-matching

I have two arrays, one with usernames and the other with played games, I want to match the profile picture that is in the username array to the yourName in played games however I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
for(id object in self.playedGames){
    PFObject *obb = object;

    for(int l = 0; l <self.Userarray1.count;l++){
    if([[obb objectForKey:@"yourName"]isEqual:[[self.Userarray1 valueForKey:@"username"]objectAtIndex:l]] ){

            PFFile *imageFile = [[self.Userarray1 valueForKey:@"profilePic"]objectAtIndex:l];

            if(imageFile !=nil){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
                NSURL* imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageFile.url];

                    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
                    UIImage *newImageset = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                        UIImageView *imgVew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 50, 50)];
                        imgVew.image = newImageset;
                        imgVew.opaque = YES;
                        [ImageArray addObject:imgVew];
                        NSLog(@"imageArray count = %i",ImageArray.count);
                        if(ImageArray.count == self.playedGames.count){
                            [self getStuff];

                        }

                    });

                 });


            }
            else{
                UIImage *NoPP = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_tab.png"];
                NoPP = [self imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)withImage:NoPP];
                UIImageView *NoPPView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 50, 50)];
                NoPPView.image = NoPP;
                NoPPView.opaque = YES;
                [ImageArray addObject:NoPPView];

            }
            }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized that i was doing asynchronous work and synchronous work so the ImageArray was being added at different times so I fixed it with this solution

```
                if(imageFile !=nil){
                UIImageView *imgVew = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 50, 50)];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
                NSURL* imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageFile.url];

                    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
                    UIImage *newImageset = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

                        imgVew.image = newImageset;
                        imgVew.opaque = YES;


                    });

                 });
                [ImageArray addObject:imgVew];
                NSLog(@"imageArray count = %i",ImageArray.count);
                if(ImageArray.count == self.playedGames.count){
                    [self getStuff];

                }

            }
```

it also made iterating through that function faster as well